# Arguments for my Base constructor are missing?

Tags: c#, derived-class

I am working on a derived class, I have linked the derived class to the parent class, I am setting up the constructor in the derived class, but I get the error that "The values don't exist in the current context" When they are already declared in the parent class.  What is the cause of this, and how can it be fixed?

Parent class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace HousingNameSpace
{
    public abstract class Housing
    {
        private int sqFt;
        private int zip;
        private int yrBlt;

        public Housing(int TSqFt, int Tzip, int TyrBlt)
        {
            sqFt = TSqFt;

            zip = Tzip;
            yrBlt = TyrBlt;
        }

       public int SqFt
       {

           get { return sqFt; }

           set { sqFt = value; }
       }


    public int ZIP
    {

        get { return zip; }

        set { zip = value; }



       }
       public int YrBlt
       {
           get{ return yrBlt; }

           set { yrBlt = value; }

       }



       public abstract double GetRentAmmount();
   }
  }
```

Derived class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HousingNameSpace;

namespace MultiTennant
{
public class Multi:Housing
{
    private string buildingtype;
    private int occupants;

    public string BuildingType
    {
        get{ return buildingtype; }

        set { buildingtype = value; }

    }

    public int Occupants
    {
        get { return occupants; }

        set { occupants = value; }

    }

    public Multi (string TbuildType) : base (TSqrFt, Tzip,TyrBlt)
    { }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to take your base constructor parameters in your child class' constructor.

```
public Multi (string TbuildType, int TSqrFt, int Tzip, int TyrBlt) 
    : base (TSqrFt, Tzip,TyrBlt)
```

A style note: Name your variables more legibly. `squareFootage`, `yearBuilt` etc... You'll thank yourself later.

Oh, and I know this isn't related to the question at all (sorry), but if I can make another suggestion:

```
public enum BuildingType
{
    House,
    Apartment,
    Condo
    //etc
}

public interface IHousing
{
    int SquareFootage { get; set; }
    int YearBuilt { get; set; }
    int ZipCode { get; set; }
    int MaximumOccupants { get; set; }    
    int MortgageAmount { get; }    
    int RentalIncome { get; } 
    BuildingType BuildingType { get; }
}


public class MultiPersonHouse 
    : IHousing
{
    public int SquareFootage { get; set; }
    public int YearBuilt { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
    public int MaximumOccupants { get; set; }

    public int MortgageAmount { get; private set; }    
    public int RentalIncome { get; private set;} 
    public BuildingType BuildingType { get; private set;}

    public MultiPersonHouse(int squareFootage, int yearBuilt /*etc...*/)
    {
        //set properties.
        this.BuildingType = BuildingType.House;
        this.MortgageAmount = 0; //Free!
        this.RentalIncome = 0; //Free rent too!
    }
}
```

And then one for each housing type. You probably want to make MaximumOccupants get only though. Wouldn't want someone changing your maximum occupancy.

Comment: @poke You're totally right... my bad. Didn't use VS to code it up. Fixed